# Deleting raw pointers from std::vector

Tags: c++, stdvector

I have following pattern:

1. I have a `std::vector` containing raw pointers to objects (I know raw pointers are "evil", but it's legacy software needing to be maintained).
2. Now for each element in the vector I need to do a test and if the test is positive do something with the pointer, delete it and then remove it from the vector:

**Pseudo code:**

```
for each pointer in vector
{
  if (SomeTest(pointer))
  {
     DoSomething(pointer)
     delete pointer
     remove pointer from vector
  }
}
```

I'm unable to come up with some nice clean code for this.

[This link](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2018/09/18/how-to-remove-pointers-from-a-vector-in-cpp/) provides different approaches, but they all look more or less cumbersome to me.

Cumbersome solution I'm using now:

```
for(auto &  p : v)
{
   if (SomeTest(p))
   {
       DoSomething(p);
       delete p;
       p = nullptr;
   }
}

v.erase(std::remove(v.begin(), v.end(), nullptr), v.end());
```

Comment: sorry, nitpick: raw pointers to objects owned by someone else are rather harmless. Only owning raw pointers are evil

Comment: The only concern I can think of is invalidating the iterator, and messing up your loop, which wouldn't have anything to do with the pointer. Perhaps you could post a [mcve]. (consider std::remove_if ?)

Comment: What specifically is wrong with the erase_if?

Comment: *I know raw pointers are "evil", but it's legacy software needing to be maintained* What version of C++ are you allowed to use?  Can you partially upgrade it to use the proper mechanics?

Comment: @user463035818 Needless to say, `delete`ing raw pointers only makes sense specifically in the evil case of owning raw pointers. The statement in the question does not explicitly attribute ownership to the pointers so you're _technically_ correct to nitpick.

Comment: @MaxLanghof if the vector is responsible to `delete` them then I would say the vector owns them. Anyhow, I was specifically refering to "I know raw pointers are "evil"" and I am a bit picky whem something gets the "evil" attribute. Too easily this can lead to misunderstanding

Comment: @MaxLanghof in my case the vector _is_ owning the pointers.

Comment: @NathanOliver upgrading to use proper mechanics would be quite long, but, yes, that would definitely be the best solution. I can use C++17.

Comment: @Jabberwocky That was my point. You didn't spell it out in black and white next to the "evil pointers" part, so _technically_ the guy's nitpick is warranted, but I wanted to point out that it is obvious their nitpick does not apply here.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

As often the answer is: know your `<algorithm>`s (and is a good reminder to myself) ;)

[`std::partition`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition) is what you're looking for: `std::partition(begin, end, p)` "moves" the elements of the range [`begin`, `end`) which *do not* satisfy the predicate `p` at the end of the range; you can then treat them as a batch.

```
auto const to_be_removed = std::partition(begin(v), end(v), [](auto p){ /* predicate */ });
std::for_each(to_be_removed, end(v), [](auto p) {
    /* crunch */
    delete p;
});
v.erase(to_be_removed, end(v));
```

---

#### Full program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector v = { new int{0}, new int{1}, new int{2} };

    // let's delete all even values
    auto const to_be_removed = std::partition(begin(v), end(v), [](auto p){ return *p % 2 != 0; });
    std::for_each(to_be_removed, end(v), [](auto p) {
        std::cout << "Deleting value " << *p << "...\n";
        delete p;
    });
    v.erase(to_be_removed, end(v));
}
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8b07bfe1deb5e6d3)

#### To go further

This implementation has two major drawbacks: the order from the vector is not stable (1), it could be factored into a reusable function (2).

- (1) is solved by `std::stable_partition`.
- (2) is not that hard:

```cpp
template<class InputIt, class UnaryPredicate, class UnaryDeleter>
InputIt delete_if(InputIt begin, InputIt end, UnaryPredicate p, UnaryDeleter d)
{
    auto const to_be_removed = std::stable_partition(begin, end, std::not_fn(p));
    std::for_each(to_be_removed, end, [d](auto p) { d(p) ; delete p; });
    return to_be_removed;
}

template<class Container, class UnaryPredicate, class UnaryDeleter>
auto delete_if(Container& c, UnaryPredicate p, UnaryDeleter d)
{
    using std::begin, std::end;
    return c.erase(delete_if(begin(c), end(c), p, d), end(c));
}
```

**Usage**:

```
delete_if(v, SomeTest, DoSomething);
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bc6a951af8473a26)

Comment: Also, `delete p`  should be handled by the `UnaryDeleter`, otherwise it can only be used for dynamic pointers.

Comment: I disagree on that point; my reasoning is that we're solving OP's specific problem: _"for each element in the vector I need to do a test and if the test is positive do something with the [raw] pointer, delete it and then remove it from the vector"_. There's no reason for them to not put the `delete` statement on the `delete_if` function.

Answer (score 14):

You can use `std::remove_if` I am not sure why the article you linked uses `std::remove_if` *before* deleting the pointers because that won't work. You have to *delete* the pointers *before* the removal:

```
std::vector<int*> v;

v.erase(std::remove_if(std::begin(v), std::end(v), [](int* p){

    // do your test and do not remove on failure
    if(!SomeTest(p))
        return false; // keep this one

    DoSomething(p);

    // Now we remove but be sure to delete here, before the
    // element is moved (and therefore invalidated)

    delete p;

    return true; // signal for removal

}), std::end(v));
```

**Notes:** Why this is safe.

Deleting the pointer does not modify the pointer itself, but the object being pointed to. That means that no elements are modified with this approach.

The standard at `C++17 28.6.8 5` guarantees that the predicate will be called just once for each element.

Comment: Responding to your comment, yes: that's a good idea for this specific case. (+1)

Answer (score 6):

The simplest solution - starting from the linked article - is to take the `erase_if` function

```
template <typename Container, typename Pred>
void erase_if(Container &c, Pred p)
{
    c.erase(std::remove_if(std::begin(c), std::end(c), p), std::end(c));
}
```

and just call it with

```
erase_if(v, [](T *pointer)
         {
           if (SomeTest(pointer))
           {
              DoSomething(pointer);
              delete pointer;
              return true; //remove pointer from vector
           }
           return false;
         });
```

You can obviously split your predicate in two if you want to separate the SomeTest/DoSomething part from the `delete` part:

```
template <typename Container, typename Pred>
void delete_if(Container &c, Pred p)
{
    auto e = std::remove_if(std::begin(c), std::end(c),
        [&p](Container::value_type *pointer)
        {
          if (p(pointer)) {
            delete pointer;
            return true;
          }
          return false;
        });
    c.erase(e, std::end(c));
}
```

Since you haven't said *why* you don't like the `erase_if` you linked yourself, I can't guess whether this has the same problem.

Comment: There's an issue with this approach: `std::erase_if(...)` is equivalent to `v.erase(std::remove_if(...))`, which [explicitly specifies](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) that the predicate *must not modify the element*.

Comment: @You Technically it doesn't modify the element, but I guess the spirit is that `p` should be idempotent (callable many times without harm), and this is certainly not so in this case as the next call on the deleted pointer will probably have UB.

Comment: Fair point. (I believe the exact wording is "The [predicate] shall not apply any non-constant function through the dereferenced iterator.", which `delete`ing technically doesn't do I guess since it's fine to `delete` a const pointer.)

Comment: @ArneVogel The standard guarantees the predicate will only be called once per element

Comment: I assume you are deducing this from [(alg.remove/5)](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/algorithms#alg.remove-5) – IMO it's still a bit of a technicality. If I was doing a code review, I'd suggest switching to `partition`/`stable_partition` or writing a meaningful comment for why it is correct.

Answer (score 2):

With the following approach first you split the elements to be deleted, then you delete, then you adjust the vector.

```
auto badIt = std::stable_partition(std::beging(v), std::end(v), SomeTestInverse);
std::for_each(badIt, std::end(v), [](auto e){ DoSomething(e); delete e;});
v.erase(badIt,std::end(v));
```

The predicate provided must be true for element to keep in order to work, as elements failing the predicate are in the last range.

Answer (score 0):

Assumed you have a vector of int pointer. Here is my solution:

```
vector<int*> vpi;

for (vector<int*>::iterator it = vpi.begin(); it != vpi.end(); )
{
    if (SomeTest(*it))
    {
        DoSomething(*it)
        int* old = *it;
        it = vpi.erase(it);
        delete old;
    } else
    {
       it++;
    }
}
```

Comment: not sure but as I understood the question this is the code that OP would like to avoid writing.

Comment: @LocTran I usually do `it = vector.erase(it)` .. not so nice as your old, new :)

Comment: Why use `old`?  `DoSomething(*it)
        delete *it;
        it = vpi.erase(it);` does the same thing.

Comment: @NathanOliver good to know someone else does the same as well

Comment: if you delete *it, the original pointer will lose or not (undefined). The better way that we should save old pointer

Comment: This solution is O(N^2) (think about the elements which need to be moved when you erase in the middle). Use `std::partition` followed by a single `erase` instead.

Comment: @LocTran What do you mean *the original pointer will lose or not (undefined)*?  If you ease the element from the vector immediately after there isn't any issue.  having `old` doesn't make the operation any safer.  It only clutters the code.

Comment: Not much different than what you are doing. What does it bring tot he mix? Threading is not safer, and that's the only reason why you might have this temporary.

Comment: @rustyx, I don't think this solution is O(N^2). It is O(N). Why O(N^2) ? could you explain?

Comment: Consider a vector with 1000 elements, of which first 100 need to be removed. How many times an element that remains would need to be moved inside the vector (around 95000).

Comment: @rustyx good to know the std::partition. it's the first time I saw that function

Answer (score 0):

Some approach that I would use:

```
for (auto i = vector.begin(); i != vector.end(); ++i) {
  if (SomeTest(*i)) {
    DoSomething(*i);
    delete *i;
    *i = nullptr;
  }
}
vector.erase(std::remove(vector.begin(), vector.end(), nullptr), vector.end());
```

Comment: That's more or less what I'm doing now

Comment: @UmNyobe What is wrong with using `nullptr` as a magic value?

Comment: @Galik maybe the vector does contain `nullptr` and maybe `SomeTest` returns `false` for a `nullptr`

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple.  YAGNI.  No reason to solve a more generic and complicated version of the problem in the off chance you will need it (hint: you won't), or hunt for obscure STL methods (well, unless you *wish* to).

```
size_t target = 0;
for (size_t idx = 0; idx < v.size(); idx++) {
    if (should_delete(v[idx]))
        delete v[idx];
    else
        v[target++] = v[idx];
}
v.resize(target);
```

Comment: `<algorithm>` is not a bunch of _"obscure STL methods"_. Learn them, use them. They produce easy to read, easy to maintain, easy to optimise code.

Comment: Of course, "easy" is in the eye of the beholder, but I've seen too many code with multiple levels of templatized inheritance which could have been written in a simple for loop or switch statement, only if the programmer resisted the urge to generalize everything to the maximum.  If anyone finds `std::for_each` with lambdas easier than `for`, then it's their taste: but I doubt it will be faster.

Comment: _"Of course, "easy" is in the eye of the beholder"_ No it is generally not. If an idiom exist in the C++ community, anything other than that idiom is not easy to read and increments the wtf/line of your codebase. About optimization, nothing can be said without testing, but generally idiomatic code and code relying on the standard library are better understood by the compiler and optimized in a better way.

Comment: ...Easy is *not* in the eye of the beholder? I'm glad you agree that `for` loop is objectively superior! :P Jokes aside, a `for` loop *has been* the idiom of C++ since it was called "C with classes", and unlike C-style strings, it's not going anywhere. Stroustrup himself warned against "trying to write C++ as if it's $(other languages)" in his "The C++ Programming Language" (2nd Ed): I'm not sure if he changed stances later, but C++ is not exactly a functional language, and trying to write C++ as if it's one can easily end up in an overcomplicated mess.

Comment: There's probably no harm in changing a single `for` loop to `for_each`, but it's silly to claim  the latter is objectively superior just because it's new. C++ has no shortage of features that scream "Just because you *can* use it here doesn't necessarily mean it's a good idea to."

Comment: `for_each` is often a poor replacement for a good'ol `for` loop, on that I totally agree. i'm talking about all the other 103 algorithms.